# How set same position + size to multiple path at once?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

A SVG file contains multiple different shapes/path at different positions and in different sizes. Working on this file in Illustrator I would like to give all these paths the same position and size (e.g. all position at 0/0 with size 64/64px).

Selecting one path at a time and setting these coordinates + size in the property editor is no problem. However, when selecting multiple path, they are sized and positions according to their common bonding box and not individually.

Is there an option in Illustrator to batch position+size all paths at once?

Comment: This question is better suited to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ unless you plan to do this programmatically, in which case you would need to show us the code you have so far

Comment: At the very least it wouldn't hurt if you show a couple of screenshoots: what you're having and what your desired output looks like.